# IDEA как добавить tools вниз?

Tags: intellij-idea

к сожалению, не получилось решить без вашего участия. Чат GPT тоже не помог.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы эта панель, была внизу. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Answer (score -1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашёл, вдруг кому-то поможет. Кстати, чат GPT помог в итоге ))))